# Implicit coercion of a value of type X to an unrelated type X

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Hi
I have this error :

> Implicit coercion of a value of type X to an unrelated type X

where X is the type of the object and yes it's `type X to an unrelated type X`.
It appears 6 times in my project, in 3 differents .mxml file, in the script element. It's in 3 files that I'm not editing and the file I has changing has no link with the 3 files with the errors.

Here a line of code with the problem.

```
var loadApplicationEvent:LoadApplicationEvent = new LoadApplicationEvent(application);
```

It was working perfect an when it was compiling and other file that I changed, it put me and error.

Bug from Flash Builder or Flex? Or not?
How can I get ride of it?

Comment: Post at least one of the lines that is showing this error.

Comment: Have you properly checked the data types of the variables in the lines you get the errors?

Comment: I add a line of code with the error. It can't be wrong!

Comment: Provide the (constructor and header at least) code for the custom Event?

Comment: I just started having the same problem in FB 4.6. Change a file, get the error. Change it again (add a space, whatever) and resave, now it works. Wash, rinse, repeat, over and over. It gives the error every other compilation. Very annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have recently started having this problem with FlashBuilder and here's what I did.

Starting with:

```
    protected var _foo:FooType;
(X) public function get foo():FooType { return this._foo; }
```

(where (X) is the error in the form Snote described it, with X = FooType)

change to:

```
    protected var _foo:FooType;
    public function get foo():* { return this._foo; }
```

and rebuild.  The * type always passes type checking no matter what, so the error disappears.

Then change it back:

```
    protected var _foo:FooType;
    public function get foo():FooType { return this._foo; }
```

The error message then disappears, at least for a while.

So far this technique seems to be reliable, if annoying.

Comment: I had this problem too, but my much simpler solution was to go to `Project` -> `Clean`. That seems to fix it.

Comment: +1 because it is probably the "right way to do it", but practically it takes a lot longer to do a clean rebuild of a large project.  The advantage of touching a single file is that the rebuild is generally optimized, and the fix appears to work just as well.

Comment: For me a clean was not helpful, but a flashbuilder restart fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into this issue myself with Flash Builder 4.5.  The return type is exactly as it should be.

The solution for me was to do a full rebuild of the project via: Project -> Clean.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by disabling "*strict type checking*"

Project properties > ActionScript Compiler > Enable strict type checking

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me. But this did. Although it's not ideal, at least I can continue with my work.

Comment: What I don't understand is that my project was building successfully for days and then all of a sudden these errors came up.  I also had to disable strict type checking to be able to continue.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you try to assign a different type object to some variable. For example, if you try to assign a string value('4') to an object where an int(4) is expected. Look for all the given locations and correct the type casting.

Comment: I edit my message and put some code. If you try to assign a string value('4') to an object where an int(4) is expected, the error would be `Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type int` but the message that I have is `Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type String`

Comment: @Snote They could be two different `String` classes. Are they both from the same namespace?

Answer (score 0):

It is an implicit casting, but I cannot tell you the precise problem with the information you have provided.

```
var loadApplicationEvent:LoadApplicationEvent = new LoadApplicationEvent(application);
```

What type of object is "application" and what argument is expected by the LoadApplicationEvent constructor?  That is where your implicit coercion is occurring.  My guess is "application" is not the same type as expected by LoadApplicationEvent in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In my case is was going every thing right. Thus it looks to be a IDE problem, as the same code worked few times and the other time it showed me this error. You can try few steps to solve this problem
1. Clear the compiled code and compile again. (There is a clear option in Project tab).
2. Create the a file with the same code and delete the old file.
3. If all this doesn't work, make another class which inherits the base class and change the expected value to * 
example:

```
   
       public class DataGroupOX extends DataGroup
       .....
       public function set itemRenderer2(value:*):void{
            value = value as IFactory;
            super.itemRenderer = value;
        }
```